# passing a javascript element id into php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got a javascript function to make date and time update automatically.

Here is the script I found from this URL: http://jsfiddle.net/pLsgJ/1/

```
setInterval(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date ( );    
    var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );   
    var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );   
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );
    currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;   
    currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;    
    var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";    
    currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;    
    currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;    
    var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = currentTimeString;
}, 1000);
```

Then to show the result we have to call the id with HTML like this:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
```

But I want to passing the result on PHP like this:

```
$timer = $_GET['timer'];
```

But it's totally failed. Is that possible to passing a javascript element id into php? How can I do that?

Help me please

Comment: Probably some Ajax stuff, which means, I'm out of here.

Comment: Can you please detail further what you mean when you say "I want to passing the result on PHP". Is this a PHP page?

Comment: @ScottL yes the PHP page. with HTML it showing result like "12:12:32 AM" then I want to get that with PHP not with HTML so I can save the time result on my database.

Answer (score 2):

create a hidden field in form

```
<form id= "myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="timer" id="timer" value="">
</form>
```

JS :-

```
$('#timer').val() = currentTimeString;
$('form#myform').submit();  // for submit after value set may be work not tested
```

and on submit of form you will get :-

```
$timer = $_GET['timer'];
```

Comment: thanks but is that possible get the $timer without any submit button?

Comment: Why submit? You will always reload your page. Better use ajax and just send your timer value instead of reloading the full page after form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables are created locally. So on the your Computer. PHP variables are created on your server.

To send javascript values from your local client back to the server you need a form, or an ajax request.

Here is a simple jQuery Ajax Request:

```
$.get( "example.php", { timervalue: mytimevalue } );
```

With this script you can send your local "mytimevalue" to your server.

Comment: how post will get in GET

Comment: Changed it. But i guess he is only looking for a way to get these values on the server. So .post or .get should be make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

sending it in a form is an option as said, or by using ajax.  But the simplest way would be to set it into a cookie with JS, then read the cookie out with PHP.

JS

`document.cookie="timer=" + timer;`

PHP

`$timer = $_COOKIE["timer"];`

here Ill add the line in for you:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var currentTime = new Date ( );    
  var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );   
  var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );   
  var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );
  currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;   
  currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;    
  var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";    
  currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;    
  currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;    
  var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = currentTimeString;
  document.cookie="timer=" + currentTimeString;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I'm interesting to your answer. It's seem can help me, but in which part should I add the JS code? inside the body tag or somewhere? Sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: Put it inside your interval function